# What are common GIS filters that would be used in a spreadsheet-like interface

Tags: geometry, gis, geography

I have a spreadsheet-like application where a column may be a `GEOGRAPPHY` type, for example something like `POINT(1 1)`. I haven't used GIS too much personally, and so was curious what is the most common filter that someone might apply to a `GEO` column. Giving a basic comparison, in Excel on a `TEXT` column, I would most commonly do something like `=value`, displaying the available values in a list of checkboxes:

[image]

My thought having zero experience other than using things like Google Maps or Kayak is that a user may want to see something like:

- Value within [Distance] [units] of [Place]

For example, "Point is within 10 miles of Chicago, Illinois". And the reverse would be "outside of". Is this the most popular filter type, or are there others that are used frequently?

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.